# Flutter - Play audio without stopping the current playback

Tags: flutter, audio

I am searching for an audio library, which is able to play an asset sound without stopping the current playback (spotify, any other music player). Maybe you have some recommendations.

What I tried so far:

- audioplayers (features is available, but library has too many bugs for a productive app)
- assets_audio_player (feature not available, but very stable in my case)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio).

There's a closed [issue](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/295) that mentions the functionality you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thx. I will have a look at it. I thought it would be easier, than evaluating every lib :-)